# equalities of localisations by 10

Tags: abstract-algebra

I denote by $R_{10}$ the localisation of a ring R by $10$.
I see in a proof of an exercice that $3\mathbb{Z}_{10} = 15 \mathbb{Z}_{10}$
but I don't understand.

If the statement above is true, then $\mathbb{Z}_{10} = 5 \mathbb{Z}_{10}$,
but $7/10\notin 5 \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, which is a contradiction?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you mean $\, 10^{-1} R\,$ then $5$ is a unit since $\,1/5 = 2/10\,$ so $\,5I = I\,$ for any ideal $\,I\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually,
$${7 \over 10}={70 \over 100} = {5 \cdot 14 \over 100} \in 5\mathbb Z_{10}$$